# Comparison between pointer and integer GCC

Tags: c

I am getting an error and I can't tell why.  Someone else had this error but they said it was because they used double quotes instead of a single quote but when I use a single quote it doesn't fix the issue.  Can someone please tell me why I am still getting this error?

P.S. it doesn't stop my code from working, I would just like my code to be error free.

[image]

I tried changing the = sign to a double = sign but that doesn't allow my code to work properly.  I thought it might have been because there's an integer someone where but it's all just single characters.

Comment: Please do not upload images of code and errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Keenan Norris Pay attention to that you are using the assignment operator = instead of the comparison operator == in if statements

Comment: Why are you assigning `grade` in each condition `=` instead of comparing with `==`?

Comment: If the code still isn't working it might be because [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Try `scanf(" %c", &grade);` with the added space.

Comment: That's certainly a potential flaw in the program, @WeatherVane, but I don't see any way that it could cause a compile-time warning.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what warning? After changing the `=` to `==` the OP's code still does not work properly.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the OP says "I am getting an error" but "it doesn't stop my code from working", so that's a compiler warning.  And the title narrows it down to "Comparison between pointer and integer", which is indeed a warning that GCC sometimes issues.

Answer (score 1):

Single `=` is an assignment. Double `==` is a comparison. If your code doesn't work when using comparison, the problem lies elsewhere.

In addition to that, [scanf doesn't ignore whitespace when reading characters like it does for reading ints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/7316365), try with `" %c"`.

Comment: Indeed, the problem lies elsewhere.  Everything in this answer is true, but that does not make it an answer to the question posed.